# permissions are gone when app is removed from background

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am asking for permissions on android app on runtime on Marshmallow and above devices. The permissions are granted properly but as soon as I killed the app (remove from background not force stop)the permissions are gone and it asks for permissions again when you again open the app.

```
boolean granted=checkPermission();
    Log.d("Permission already there","---"+granted );// it always returns false

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        System.out.println("Build version is"+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        if(!granted){
            requestPermission();
        }
    }


  private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,

    },RequestPermissionCode);

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

    case RequestPermissionCode:

        if (grantResults.length > 0) {

            boolean ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean RECORD_AUDIO = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean CALL_PHONE = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean CAMERA = grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean GET_ACCOUNTS = grantResults[5] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean READ_CONTACTS = grantResults[6] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;



            if (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION && RECORD_AUDIO && CALL_PHONE && CAMERA && WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && GET_ACCOUNTS && READ_CONTACTS) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        break;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermission() {


    int FirstPermissionResult= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int SecondPermissionResult=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    int ThirdPermissionResult=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    int FourthPermissionResult=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int FifthPermissionResult=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int SixthPermissionResult=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    int SeventhPermissionResult=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

    return FirstPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            SecondPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ThirdPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
            FourthPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            FifthPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            SixthPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            SeventhPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Android source and docs in `PackageManager`

```
public static final int PERMISSION_DENIED = -1;
public static final int PERMISSION_GRANTED = 0;
```

and in your code, you are adding up permission results of all the Permissions. So even if for one item permission is not granted, your `result` variable becomes `-1` and your method returns false;

Another issue with your code is, you are asking permissions for stuffs like `VIBRATE` please read this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) to know the difference between normal and dangerous permissions.

Last but the most important issue, asking all the runtime permissions at once is not recommended by google. And there are also chances that App store will reject your app for not following permissions guidelines

EDIT:
remove these permissions from your list and try again

```
Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT
Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT
Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
Manifest.permission.VIBRATE
```

> Please read the doc, it clearly mentioned that you don't ask `run time permissions` for `normal permissions`

Comment: I am granting all permissions still it returns false everytime when I reopen my app.

Comment: I added the list of permissions that you must remove from the list.

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en read this too

Comment: Its working.Thanx a lot. But Phone permission is not getting granted.

Comment: Call phone? Did you declare it in Manifest?

Comment: Sorry it was working on naugat but not in Marshmallow. Again the same problem is there. I have updated my code.